Python - Flask - cannot use flask run - The system cannot find the file specified
After having installed my environment, I just try to run my flask app
It works fine using python
.\venv\Scripts\python.exe .\src\main.py --debug

But as I try to run this
.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
flask.exe app .\src\main.py               

I get
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"******\venv\scripts\python.exe"  "******\venv\Scripts\flask.exe" app src\main.py': The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried
.\venv\Scripts\flask.exe app .src\main.py

I get this
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"*****\venv\scripts\python.exe"  "****\venv\Scripts\flask.exe" app .\src\main.py': The system cannot find the file specified.


flask.exe is not in the path
I already checked other related answers on this subject, yet nothing works

Is there something I am missing ?
Thanks for your help

It appears that you have installed flask outside of your virtual environment, or the script you are trying to run is not a flask application.

And  .\venv\Scripts\flask.exe --app  .src\main.py run  ?   usually I use "flask --app myapp run"   if myapp.py is the file where I defined my flask app

@rehaqds yeah but I want to debug the app

You can just add --debug at the end. If it works for you I will write an answer.

gotta try that, busy on something else

I already have --debug at the end, I just cannot trace the code
